# Problems after installation of git Bash

Tags: windows, git-bash

After git bash installation I lost option to create new file from right click context menu folder in Windows 10.
When I right click on desktop instead of "new" there is only get Gui Here and Git Bash here, option to create new is invisible.

After I uninstalled Git Bash from pc I lost it all, there is no git and create new folder settings.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling Git bash would uninstall [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) itself.

As an alternative, it is best to install it *without* the Windows Explorer integration, and to use the regular "Open command window here." contextual menu option:

[image: https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/open-command-window-here-650x485.png?trim=1,1&bg-color=000&pad=1,1]

Then you can type "bash", and you are in a bash session.